# Rails: Is devise vulnerable to session hijacking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) vulnerable to session hijacking over a normal http:// connection? I am having trouble figuring it out from the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.** Rails' default way to manage sessions is susceptible to hijacking.

This is because it transmits to the client all the information the client further requires to identify itself in HTTP cookies. For the most part, anybody who can intercept the HTTP connection can assume the identity of the client from Rails' perspective.

The simplest countermeasure is to only serve your site via HTTPS and have Rails issue `secure` cookies, which tells the browser only to send that cookie via HTTPS. The [security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) has more helpful tips.

Comment: What a bummer that such a popular plugin for such a popular web framework has insecure default behavior.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [this email on Devise discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plataformatec-devise/B7aN1AGnlco), security setup for the application is in the domain of the main application (in this case, Rails, I assume).

Do check out the [RailsCast episode - Dangers of Session Hijacking](http://railscasts.com/episodes/356-dangers-of-session-hijacking) to deal with session hijacking at the Rails Application level.

[Rails Security Guide's section on Session Hijacking](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-hijacking) is another must read resource.

Devise provides for forcing SSL only cookies by setting `:secure => true` in the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file of a Rails App.

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean by "provides for forcing SSL only cookies"? I know what SSL and cookies are, but not sure exactly what SSL only cookies are.

Comment: That's from the RailsCast episode I linked. It is explained there towards the end how to setup the rails application such that it creates two cookies - one of which is secure. Check out that 6 minute video. Or if video isn't your thing, read [the asciicast version](http://railscasts.com/episodes/356-dangers-of-session-hijacking?view=asciicast) :-)

Comment: Yes, I've watched that video a couple of times. One question I had from watching it, is does it require the login to happen on https? I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to prevent hijacking, using devise all on http.

Comment: [Making devise views into SSL](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-SSL-%28HTTPS%29)

Comment: @KevinM  `if it's possible to prevent hijacking, using devise all on http` : no it's not with cookies. To prevent this you need HTTPS and that `:secure => true` option will just tell your browser to send that cookie only when https connection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly). That beeing said there are other options to replace session store that will solve the issue http://dev.housetrip.com/2014/01/14/session-store-and-security/